# Number of different terms inside mathematical expression

Tags: functions, counting

I have expressions of the form $OpA[x\_,y\_]$ and $OpB[x\_,y\_]$ ocurring inside mathematical expressions. I want to create a function which does the following:

```
CountOperations[expr_]:={number of different expressions of the form OpA[x_,y_] inside expr, number of... OpB[x_,y_] inside expr]}
```

For example, it should do the following:

```
In: test=OpA[x,y];
In: CountOperations[test]
Out: {1,0}
In: test=(OpA[1,2]*OpA[2,3]+OpA[1,2]OpB[x,a])/OpB[1,2];
In: CountOperations[test]
Out: {2,2}
```

because the different expressions are $OpA[1,2]$, $OpA[2,3]$, $OpB[x,a]$ and $OpB[1,2]$. The second $OpA[1,2]$ shall be neglected as it is a duplicate.

So far I have been trying to replace all $Plus$, $Times$ and $Power$ functions with $List$, flatten the list and delete the duplicates, but there must be a better way.

I would be happy if you could help me.

**Edit:** I wrote polynomials, but I mean general expressions with denominators. Actually, a function for polynomials would be sufficient, but I want to keep everything consistent.

Comment: `test` does not seem to be a polynomial to me, since you divide by `OpB[1,2]`. Is integer powers of the Op general enough?

Comment: Oh, you're right... I messed up the definition... I meant general expressions involving those functions. I will have this fixed.

Comment: `Length@Variables@test` might do it.  It depends on the range of use-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countOperations[expr_] := 
(Length@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, #, Infinity]) & /@ {OpA[___], OpB[___]}
```

should do the trick. Cases lists all occurences at any level (down to level `Infinity` in the expression tree), and then we discard duplicates and take the `Length`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This appears like the function I have been looking for. I will give it a try and, if it indeed works, vote this as the answer to my question.

Comment: I suggest you let it sit for a day or two before accepting, as there might be better answers out there, waiting to be written :)

Comment: Thanks for that tip, too. But what I can already tell is that it's working perfectly well so far.